# How to use DATEADD and WEEKDAY together In DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to figure out a way to look at previous days sales and what percentage above or below we are but only during the Weekday as we don't ship or sell anything on the weekends.

This works very well but when I toggle my filter for say a Monday the Variance percentage becomes blank as it is looking at Sunday and Not Friday.

SalesYesterday = CALCULATE('Measures - Sales'[TotalDollarSales],
Dateadd('Shipping and Service Table'[PackingSlipCreatedDate],-1,DAY))

SalesVariance = 'Measures - Sales'[TotalDollarSales]-[SalesYesterday]

SalesVariance% = DIVIDE([SalesVariance],[SalesYesterday])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the amount of days you look back dynamically, mondays you go back 3 days, the rest you keep your -1 rule. And you could even not return values for Saturdays and Sundays.

```
SalesYesterday = 
    VAR _weekday = WEEKDAY(MAX('Shipping and Service Table'[PackingSlipCreatedDate]))
    VAR _days = SWITCH(_weekday,2,-3,-1)
RETURN
IF(
   _weekday in {1,7}
   ,BLANK()
   ,CALCULATE(
       'Measures - Sales'[TotalDollarSales]
       ,Dateadd(
           'Shipping and Service Table'[PackingSlipCreatedDate]
           ,_days
           ,DAY
       )
   )
)
```